# If $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ is normal, show $H\cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $K$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

Working through the First Isomorphism Theorem in Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* and I want to make sure this proof is not using circular logic via my definitions or notation.

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $K$ be any subgroup of $G$. Assume for the purposes of contradiction that $H\cap K$ is not a normal subgroup of $K$. Then there must exist some $k\in K$ such that for some $b\in H\cap K$ that $kbk^{-1}\not\in H\cap K$. But since $H$ is normal, then $kbk^{-1}\in H$ since $H$ must be closed with respect to conjugates when $b\in H$. So $kbk^{-1}\not\in K$ in order for $kbk^{-1}\not\in H\cap K$. But $b$ is also in  $K$ by definition of the intersection and $k,k^{-1}\in K$. Since $K$ is a group and must be closed under its operations $kbk^{-1}\in K$ which causes our contradiction. Thus $H\cap K$ must be normal.

Thanks!

Comment: I corrected a typo in your proof. It looks fine for me, though you may find in your argument that proof by contradiction is not necessary. It's usually more helpful to think the straight way: for any $k\in K$ and $b\in H\cap K$, your argument shows $kbk^{-1}\in H\cap K$, which is exactly the definition of $H\cap K$ being a normal subgroup of $K$.

Comment: It can also be shown in a direct way !! No need to bring contradiction... Although your proofline seems fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is fine but it'd honestly be cleaned up a bit by just doing it "directly": so for instance, you can just take any $k\in K$ and $h\in H\cap K$, then note that $khk^{-1}\in H$ since $H$ is normal, and that $k,h,k^{-1}$ are all in $K$ so their product $khk^{-1}$ is in $K$. Thus we've shown $khk^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

Note this is basically the exact argument you've written, just without an unnecesary hypothesis at the beginning to end in a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Not circular--just lengthier than needed.  Rephrase it as a direct proof rather than a proof by contradiction, and that will make it shorter and easier to follow.